# Why is the word "Odometry" always recognized as a typo

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Working a lot with robots, this word is very important. Whenever I write the word odometry, I get it underlined in red. Even here in Stackoverflow. Why is that? The word has even  a Wikipedia page defining it and is everywhere in the Internet.

Comment: Honestly, this isn't a language question... it's simply the fact that the dictionary in your browser and in your other applications don't have the word listed. It seems to be a very niche term... so it seems unlikely that every dictionary would include it... and browser dictionaries, particularly, seem to have very short word collections.

Comment: As a note, SO/SE doesn't have any control over the word underlining. It's your browser doing it.

Comment: I've nominated the question for closing because it is not related to the use of the English language. It's more of a software question.

Comment: For some applications, like Microsoft Word, you can actually add words to the dictionary... if the fact that it's marked as incorrect bothers you, you should look into adding the word to your dictionary.

Comment: "even a Wikipedia page". Crowd-sourced information is not guaranteed to be a reliable indicator of a word's currency, especially if all it takes is one person in the crowd to create an entry.

Comment: @Catija: I don't disagree. I'm responding to the implications of the word "even" in the OP's remark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technical terms often don't make it into dictionaries, and it takes time for newly-coined words to make it into dictionaries.

Personally I've never heard the word "odometry" before. Maybe it's commonly used by robotics engineers. I occasionally stumble across words that aren't in my browser's dictionary or MS Word's dictionary or whatever. When it happens, I double-check the spelling and move on.

Any words highlighted by a spell-checker should be taken as POSSIBLE mis-spellings. Don't take it too seriously.